# Can there be chords in a key signature?

Tags: chords, key-signatures

I know key signatures usually, if not always have a normal note in it (C, C#, D, E, etc.). But is it possible to have a *chord* in a key signature?

Comment: What? :) Can you give an example of what you think a key signature looks like?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Either we don't have the same concept of chord or of signature ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A key signature is given at the beginning of piece of music. It tells you sharps and flats that should be applied to specific notes throughout the whole piece.

This key signature...

[image]

...means all `B's` get treated as `Bb` and all `E's` get treated as `Eb` all the other letters `A C D F G` get treated as naturals.

Being 'in a key' on a simple level means 'to use the notes specified by the key signature.'

You can have chords in the key...

[image]

...notice that no sharps or flats are used next to the chord notes, because the sharps and flats applied to the notes are given in the key signature.

You can also have chords not in the key - in the sense that additional sharps and flats not given by the key signature are added next to chord tones...

[image]

In reality 'being in a key' is more complex than simply using the 7 tones indicated by the key signature. But I won't go into those details now. The important thing is you can use chords that either "are in" the notes of the key signature or use added sharps and flats for chords that "are not in" the key signature.

Beyond what I have described about chords being in a key, there isn't really an idea of chords being "in a key signature."

Comment: Just the staff line B, and the staff 'space' E gets treated as Bb and Eb? That's pretty inaccurate!! What about any other Bb and Eb notes?

Comment: @Tim, yes, my wording was bad. I made an edit to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting wikipedia:

> A key signature designates notes that are to be played higher or lower than the corresponding natural notes and applies through to the end of the piece or up to the next key signature.

So no, the key signature is never used for example to indicate that all the A chords are to be played as A# (if I correctly understood your question).
That's because key signature indicates how you read the **notes on the staff**, while chords are just a bunch of those notes played together.

Answer (score 0):

Key signatures don't really have 'normal' notes. They show which notes are not 'normal'. By that I mean they show, using sharps or flats, that there are some specific changed notes from the naturals. In other words, those notes which are not the white keys on a piano.

That's why the key sig. of C major is blank - the key contains only the white keys on the piano. D will have two changed notes - F# and C# - so those are shown in the key sig.

As far as *chords* in the key sig. are concerned, I don't see how they could be portrayed. Chords are groups of notes, depicted by the dots like crotchets, etc. A key signature is depicted by # or b.